# Why can't i sign in to my rails app after swtiching to postgresql database, and is it related?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, devise

I am building a blog. I swtiched from sqlite3 to postgres database.  The app seemed to work fine on localhost and since swtiching the database the new database is empty. so i created a new user (or in this case author) as per the video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j6kySJ4EKs

```
author=Author.new
author.name='biggles'
author.email='biggles@boggles.com
author.password='foobar'
author.password_confirmation='foobar'
author.save
```

then the command 'author' gives:

```
irb(main):046:0> author
=> #<Author id: 1, name: "biggles", email: "biggles@boggles.com", created_at: "2018-02-11 12:17:58", updated_at: "2018-02-13 14:18:30">
```

proving that it has been saved to the database.

however when i try to log in with the email and password it says "Invalid Email or password."

The one difference that i noticed between the video and what happened with me is that on the video when he types "Author.new" there appears many more fields of entry see 15.43 in the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j6kySJ4EKs

when i type Author.new i only get

```
irb(main):047:0> Author.new
=> #<Author id: nil, name: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

This seems strange since in the Author model there are more fields than this

Author model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: authors
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                   :string
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string           default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :registerable,:timeoutable and :omniauthable

devise :database_authenticatable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      has_many :posts
    end
```

I would have thought that Author.new would show all these fields, but it doesnt only the ones mentioned above. So there is some reason why the password is not saving to the database and therefore not logging in and i can't understand why since i haven't changed any other code. i have only changed the database.yml file and added the pg gem to the gem file.

here is the last entry from the development log:

```
Started POST "/authors/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-13 14:38:50 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"K8hWxv2rJCq6nhRFAFtl0FLDiJYqBqeJQRJ8sGQRsr/e4MdPQFgaV/7Of8+wA4YHDMV5U0o7vcAPPEjel3affQ==", "author"=>{"email"=>"biggles@boggles.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  [1m[36mAuthor Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "authors"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "biggles@boggles.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"K8hWxv2rJCq6nhRFAFtl0FLDiJYqBqeJQRJ8sGQRsr/e4MdPQFgaV/7Of8+wA4YHDMV5U0o7vcAPPEjel3affQ==", "author"=>{"email"=>"biggles@boggles.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/author
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/author (162.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (8.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1576ms (Views: 1381.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Please tell me which other files i should post as edits and i will add them.

EDIT: I can only think of one thing that 'password' and 'password'_confirmation are not fields in the Author model. but i am copying the code from the video and this is what he writes. but this wouldn't explain the other missing fields when typing Author.new

EDIT 2: result of Author.all and Author.last after performing author=Author.new and author.save

```
irb(main):001:0> Author.all
  Author Load (3.9ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):002:0> Author.last
  Author Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" ORDER BY "authors"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
```

EDIT 3: result of Author.new

```
irb(main):004:0> author=Author.new
=> #<Author id: nil, name: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> author.save
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

Comment: After you do `author.save`, what happens? If you type `Author.all`; does your new user appear?

Comment: well it is very strange because before it was returning the saved authors but now it seems it is returning nil. i will add the result in an edit because the formatting will be clearer.

Comment: hi there, can you try saving the object with `save!` , it will tell you the error if any...

Comment: Have you taken a look to the code of his APP ? you will find the GitHub repository in the description of the video  `https://github.com/StephenFiser/FrogBlog` maybe it helps you to compare what is different in your code :)

Comment: If there is nothing important in the DB that you can't quickly recreate, try `rake db:drop:all`, `bundle install`, and then, `rake db:setup`. That should get any DB inline with whatever configuration your app is in. After that, try adding a new user through the app.